# Is it possible to append a script to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

i was wondering if i can add/append a javascript to an iframe which is loaded with an external web page that is not in my website. is it possible using jQuery or even simple javascript ?

```
  <script>
  // i need some code here
  </script>
  <iframe src="http://www.xxx.xxx/" id="myiframe" />
```

Note: i don't want to replace the content of the iframe, i just want to add the script

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with the iframe in your script?

Comment: If the external site is a "friendly" site - that is, you know the developers and they are happy to do this, you could ask that they pull in a script from your site - a `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute from a different domain is allowed. This can be used to apply some trickery which would allow communication with your site by either having dynamically generated scripts (i.e php, etc which outputs a js file, based on URL query strings) or setting up a XDM framework such as easyXDM. But if you don't know the author of the other site, or can't get them to add your script, its not possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible (and quite rightly too) because it violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  It would be rather a large security hole to allow users to script content that's on another domain, anything would be possible from keyhooking to stealing personal data.

Answer (score 5):

If the iframe involves content from a different domain, the browser is not going to let your code poke around in it.

Comment: There's a runaround for this which is called iframe proxy. But its a little hard to use.

Comment: @Aykut: the proxy would have to be on the hosting page's domain, and you would have to add the `<base>` tag to the document but it's a hacky solution and you'd still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible due to security policy.

However, if you really want to do it, and have understand the security issues, you could give a try to a solution like [Ajax Cross domain](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/)

Comment: I can't see how ACD can help here.  He's including the content in an iframe and ACD is just a work around for cross domain requests.  It doesn't in any way help in accessing the DOM of a different origin document.